# Spring: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, h2

I am following the tutorial at https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/ . I used the initializer and decided to use gradle. When attemting to build the application or directly run it, I'm getting the error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

I guess that's caused by the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` or `com.h2database:h2`, and probably related to some version mismatch. However, I don't know what to do about it.

My gradle.build:

```
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '2.0.0.RELEASE'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-
    plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'sfs.examples'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 9.0

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    runtime('com.h2database:h2')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Comment: You are using Java9... Java9 doesn't have Jaxb visible by default. Either use java8 or add the dependency or add --add-modules java.xml.bind` to your runtime configuration.

Comment: Ok great, thank you both, a lot. I added `compile('javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0')` to my build.gradle. Now it's running.